# Не получается восстановить образ Windows Backup при загрузке по сети в режиме UEFI

Tags: windows, uefi, pxe

Появилось желание, использую сетевую загрузку, загрузить среду восстановления Windows 10 (Windows Recovery Environment, та, которая выглядит вот так вот):
[image]

Конечная задача - загрузившись по сети, восстановить систему из образа стандартного Windows Backup.
Получилось на 3/4 :) :

- в режиме BIOS загрузка происходит с помощью pxelinux из пакета syslinux, всё работает. Но, если Windows загружалась в режиме UEFI, то восстановить этот образ в режиме BIOS невозможно, среда восстановления отказывается это делать.
- в режиме UEFI загрузиться c помощью syslinux не получилось, воспользовался для этого iPXE. В iPXE загружаю Windows Recovery Environment через wimboot следующим образом:

```
:winre
kernel wimboot
initrd http://10.1.2.52/BCD BCD 
initrd http://10.1.2.52/boot.sdi boot.sdi
initrd http://10.1.2.52/boot.wim boot.wim
boot
```

где boot.wim - просто переименованный файл WinRE.wim.
Загрузиться получается, но при выборе пункта "Восстановление образа системы" я получаю сообщение об ошибке "STATUS_WAIT_2" (0x80070002).

[image]

Возможно у кого-то получалось сделать то, что я хочу, при загрузке по сети в режиме UEFI, поделитесь, пожалуйста опытом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня так:

```
label ERD Commander 10 32,64bit over iPXE
        kernel ipxe.lkrn
        initrd ipxe.d/erd10.ipxe
```

`ipxe.d/erd10.ipxe`:

```
#!ipxe

dhcp
route

set boot-url http://172.16.11.8/
set keep-san 1
sanboot --no-describe -k ${boot-url}/tftpboot/soft/erd/dart10.iso
boot
dhcp
```

```
sha1sum soft/erd/dart10.iso 
0f7c0bedd48277aec20083261696654796def1e0  soft/erd/dart10.iso
```

Comment: Спасибо! Собрал ERD Commander, при загрузке в него восстановление из образа работает.

Comment: @VlLight, сколько компов в организации в которой ты мутишь сетевую загрузку?

Comment: около 100 компов

Comment: Рекомендую пересмотреть свою концепцию и обратить внимание на `CloneZilla`. Исошник после распаковки - отлично грузится по сети, а из-за того, что там дебиан - тебе доступен и `ssh` и `bc` и `partclone`. Даже `7z` и `jq` есть. ipxe плох тем, что поддерживает далеко не все сетевухи особенно на ноутах. Ты упрёшься в то, что надо всё равно делать флэшку и долбиться с ней. Да, есть ноуты без сети, но конкретно у нас - это пока не столь массовое явление. У нас 1500+ компов через Клонзиллу катается с 2012-го.

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Если я правильно понимаю, как работает CloneZilla - нужно загрузиться с носителя (флешка / CD / сеть), чтобы сделать резервную копию: либо физически присутствуя (ткнул кнопку включения / перезагрузил ПК с нужного носителя, выбрал в меню "Сделать резервную копию"), либо как-то ещё. Я когда-то колхозил такую схему: на всех ПК загрузкой по умолчанию выбирается сеть, скриптом в нерабочее время default-конфигурация pxelinux заменяется на вариант "начать при загрузке бэкап Clonezill'ой, после бэкапа выключиться", все машины включаются по WoL, потом default возвращается на место :)

Comment: Сейчас есть порядка 20 виндовых машин, для которых хочется иметь полный актуальный образ диска, потому что развернуть их с нуля при аварии будет от "сложно и долго" до "практически невозможно". В Windows Backup - резервное копирование делается "на лету" во время работы, соответственно, со стороны админа из задач только следить, что всё сделалось, т.к. ПК гарантированно ежедневно включаются. Хотя вот со свежеустановленной тестовой Win10 21H2 я не смог снять резервную копию стандартными средствами :( На LTSB 2016 - вроде работает. Интересно, как это делается "у взрослых".

Comment: Я не доверяю штатным средствам винды. У них есть 2 мерзкие особенности. 1. На штатку могут забить и перестать поддерживать. 2. Она не отработает в нужный момент, а на официальном сайте с вопросами будет чё-то типа "переустанови винду, мне помогло". Я бы подошёл к вопросу более въедливо и выяснил что именно на этих тачках надо бэкапить, т.е. какие именно настройки какой именно проги важно развернуть быстро. И плясал бы уже от этого.